# Присвоение id группы для при совпадении хотя бы одного из значений

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужна помощь, есть набор строк с n идентификаторами, в у некоторых строк они совпадают, нужно для строк в которых хотя бы один из идентификаторов совпадает  присвоить общий id ( id группы),. Каждая строка может входить только в одну группу.
К примеру в строках  1, 4, 8 совпадает id_a, у 8 и 9 id_b   - значит это одна группа. Совпадение только в рамках типа идентификатора , id_a = id_a и т.д.

```
SELECT 1 row_id, 'a1' id_a,  'b1' id_b, 'c1' id_x, 'd1' id_d
UNION
SELECT 2 , 'a2' id_a,  'b2' id_b, 'c2' id_x, 'd9' id_d
UNION
SELECT 3 , 'a3' id_a,  'b3' id_b, 'c3' id_x, 'd3' id_d
UNION
SELECT 4 , 'a1' id_a,  'b4' id_b, 'c4' id_x, 'd4' id_d
UNION
SELECT 5 , 'a5' id_a,  'b5' id_b, 'c5' id_x, 'd5' id_d
UNION
SELECT 6 , 'a6' id_a,  'b6' id_b, 'c6' id_x, 'd6' id_d
UNION
SELECT 7 , 'a7' id_a,  'b7' id_b, 'c7' id_x, 'd7' id_d
UNION
SELECT 8 , 'a1' id_a,  'b8' id_b, 'c8' id_x, 'd8' id_d
UNION
SELECT 9 , 'a9' id_a,  'b8' id_b, 'c9' id_x, 'd9' id_d
```

Comment: Неоднозначно. Пример: (а,б), (б,в), (в,а) - что тут группа? Соответственно нерешаемо.

Comment: Пример конкретно  по строке ``(8,'a1','b8','c8','d8')`` для 'a1' группа(1,4,8) для 'b8 группа (8,9). Недостаточное описание задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь условие стало понятнее.
Это похоже на задачу составления наибольших подсетей (связанных узлов) в сети.
Посмотрите вариант

```
-- тестовые данные
with recursive  data as(
SELECT 1 row_id, 'a1' id_a,  'b1' id_b, 'c1' id_x, 'd1' id_d
UNION
SELECT 2 , 'a2' id_a,  'b2' id_b, 'c2' id_x, 'd9' id_d
UNION
SELECT 3 , 'a3' id_a,  'b3' id_b, 'c3' id_x, 'd5' id_d
UNION
SELECT 4 , 'a1' id_a,  'b4' id_b, 'c4' id_x, 'd4' id_d
UNION
SELECT 5 , 'a5' id_a,  'b5' id_b, 'c5' id_x, 'd5' id_d
UNION
SELECT 6 , 'a6' id_a,  'b6' id_b, 'c6' id_x, 'd6' id_d
UNION
SELECT 7 , 'a7' id_a,  'b7' id_b, 'c7' id_x, 'd7' id_d
UNION
SELECT 8 , 'a1' id_a,  'b8' id_b, 'c8' id_x, 'd8' id_d
UNION
SELECT 9 , 'a9' id_a,  'b8' id_b, 'c9' id_x, 'd9' id_d
)
-- пример запроса с рекурсией
,r as(
   select 1 lvl,cast(row_id as varchar) path,row_id,id_a,id_b,id_x,id_d
   from data
  union all
  select r.lvl+1
      ,path||','||cast(d.row_id as varchar)
     ,d.row_id,d.id_a,d.id_b,d.id_x,d.id_d
  from r inner join data d 
     on (d.id_a=r.id_a or d.id_b=r.id_b or d.id_x=r.id_x or d.id_d=r.id_d)
  where strpos(path,cast(d.row_id as varchar))=0
)
,t1 as(
select * ,unnest (string_to_array(path,',') ) gr
from r
)
,t2 as(
select row_id,min(gr) gr 
from t1
group by row_id
)
select gr,STRING_AGG(cast(row_id as varchar),',' order by row_id) lst
from t2
group by gr
```

Результат

| gr | lst |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,4,8,9 |
| 3 | 3,5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |

Попробовал отразить в рисунке)
[image: Схема связей]

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то задачей подразумевается поиск одинаковых значений в столбцах.

Допустим, изначальная таблица имеет вид:

```
WITH testTable AS (
  SELECT 1 row_id, 'a1' id_a,  'b1' id_b, 'c1' id_x, 'd1' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 2 , 'a2' id_a,  'b2' id_b, 'c2' id_x, 'd9' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 3 , 'a3' id_a,  'b3' id_b, 'c3' id_x, 'd3' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 4 , 'a1' id_a,  'b4' id_b, 'c4' id_x, 'd4' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 5 , 'a5' id_a,  'b5' id_b, 'c5' id_x, 'd5' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 6 , 'a6' id_a,  'b6' id_b, 'c6' id_x, 'd6' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 7 , 'a7' id_a,  'b7' id_b, 'c7' id_x, 'd7' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 8 , 'a1' id_a,  'b8' id_b, 'c8' id_x, 'd8' id_d
  UNION
  SELECT 9 , 'a9' id_a,  'b8' id_b, 'c9' id_x, 'd9' id_d
),
```

Далее вращаем таблицу, чтобы можно было произвести поиск одинаковых значений:

```
pvt AS (
  SELECT
    pvt.col,
    pvt.val,
    pvt.row_id
  FROM
    testTable t
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        'id_a' AS col,
        t.id_a AS val,
        t.row_id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        'id_b' AS col,
        t.id_b AS val,
        t.row_id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        'id_x' AS col,
        t.id_x AS val,
        t.row_id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        'id_d' AS col,
        t.id_d AS val,
        t.row_id
    ) pvt ON true
)
```

Ищем одинаковые значения по столбцам:

```
srh AS (
  SELECT
    t1.col,
    t1.val,
    t1.row_id
  FROM
    pvt t1
  WHERE
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM pvt t2
      WHERE
        t1.col = t2.col
        AND t1.val = t2.val
        AND t1.row_id != t2.row_id
    )
  ORDER BY
    t1.col,
    t1.val,
    t1.row_id
)
```

Ну а какой вывод должен автор не указал... предполагаю так?

```
SELECT
  s.col,
  s.val,
  ARRAY_AGG(s.row_id) AS row_ids
FROM
  srh s
GROUP BY
  s.col,
  s.val
```

| col | val | row_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_a | a1 | {1, 4, 8} |
| id_b | b8 | {8, 9} |
| id_d | d9 | {2, 9} |